# PDFtron: change name of element

Tags: pdftron

I'm using PDFTron's Java SDK, and I want to change the name of an element, then write the modified PDF to a new file, but I get the following output:

```
PDFNet is running in demo mode.
Permission: read
Exception: 
     Message: SetName() can't be invoked on Obj of this type.
```

How can I change an object's name? My code (in Scala) is as follows:

```scala
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  PDFNet.initialize()

  var doc = new PDFDoc("example.pdf")
  var fdf = doc.fdfExtract
  var iter = fdf.getFieldIterator

  while (iter.hasNext) {
    var field = iter.next
    var obj = field.findAttribute("T")
    if (obj != null && field.getName.startsWith("MyPrefix")) {
      obj.setName("NewPrefix") // `field.setName` produces the same error
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API `Field.GetName()` is technically an amalgamation of this leaf Field and any parent ones, delimited by a `.`.

So while `Field.getName()` might return `name.first` the Field's `T` value might just be `first`. This is why there is `Field.getPartialName()` exists.

So the better/safer code to change the `T` value is.

```
var obj = field.findAttribute("T")
if (obj != null && obj.isString() && obj.getAsPDFText().startsWith("MyPrefix")) {
  obj.setString("NewPrefix")
}
```